# Matplotlib Python Axes sharing through plot class

Tags: matplotlib, plot, shared, figure, axes

I'm trying to create a plot class where the goal is to be able to share axes with any subsequent plots that are created. So, for example, if I create a plot with my class, leave that plot open, then create another plot with my class, I want my class to check and see if there is a current figure open (which there should be in this case) and if there is it should use the current figures axes to share with the new figure I'm trying to create. Here is the work that I have done so far. When I run this, it creates the second figure but for some reason it opens with it already pre-zoomed into a specific portion of the first figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Plott(object):

    def __init__(self,xdat=None,ydat=None):
        self.xdat = xdat
        self.ydat = ydat

    def PlotNow(self):
        if plt.get_fignums():
            f = plt.figure()
            sp = f.add_subplot(111, sharex = plt.gca(), sharey= plt.gca())            
            sp.plot(self.xdat, self.ydat,  'o-')
        else:
            f = plt.figure()
            sp = f.add_subplot(111)
            sp.plot(self.xdat, self.ydat, 'o-')
        return f
```

Here is how I run the class:

```
from Plotter import Plott
p1 = Plott(range(0,10),range(0,10))
p1.PlotNow()
p2 = Plott(range(0,10),range(0,10))
p2.PlotNow()
```

Here is what the output images look like for first and second plots respectively:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add images illustrating the current behavior? (and probably also the expected one?